# How to make C# GRPC ClientInterceptor with streaming response wait until completion before exiting

Tags: c#, asynchronous, interceptor, grpc-c#

Starting with this sample:

https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/tree/master/examples/Interceptor/Interceptor.sln

I want to change this interceptor:

https://github.com/grpc/grpc-dotnet/blob/master/examples/Interceptor/Client/ClientLoggerInterceptor.cs

I want to change this method to not return (and enter the "finally" block) until the **continuation** has completed.

I can't seem to figure out how to make the await happen without modifying the method signature and breaking the override.

```
public override AsyncServerStreamingCall<TResponse> AsyncServerStreamingCall<TRequest, TResponse>(
    TRequest request,
    ClientInterceptorContext<TRequest, TResponse> context,
    AsyncServerStreamingCallContinuation<TRequest, TResponse> continuation)
{
    LogCall(context.Method);
    AddCallerMetadata(ref context);

    // added to the example:
    var timer = new Stopwatch();
    timer.Start();

    try
    {
        return continuation(request, context);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LogError(ex);
        throw;
    }
    // added to the example:
    finally
    {
        // I want the timer to include the complete runtime of "continuation"
        _logger.LogInformation(
            $"Total elapsed time: {timer.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
    }
}
```

Comment: Basically what you need to do is to create a new instance of the AsyncServerStreamingCallContinuation delegate that acts as a "wrapper" for the existing `continuation`.   Once the "wrapper" instance is invoked, your code will run instead of the original method handler and you can call into it as needed. Basically, this allows you to write a replacement server side handler implementation that can later call the original handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```cs
public override AsyncServerStreamingCall<TResponse> AsyncServerStreamingCall<TRequest, TResponse>(
    TRequest request,
    ClientInterceptorContext<TRequest, TResponse> context,
    AsyncServerStreamingCallContinuation<TRequest, TResponse> continuation)
{
    LogCall(context.Method);
    AddCallerMetadata(ref context);

    // added to the example:
    var timer = new Stopwatch();
    timer.Start();

    var call = continuation(request, context);

    return new AsyncServerStreamingCall<TResponse>(
        new AsyncStreamReaderErrorHandler<TResponse>(
            call.ResponseStream,
            () => _logger.LogInformation($"Total elapsed time: {timer.ElapsedMilliseconds}")),
        call.ResponseHeadersAsync,
        call.GetStatus,
        call.GetTrailers,
        call.Dispose);
}
```

```cs
public class AsyncStreamReaderErrorHandler<TResponse> : IAsyncStreamReader<TResponse>
{
    private readonly IAsyncStreamReader<TResponse> _streamReader;
    private readonly Action _completionCallback;

    public AsyncStreamReaderErrorHandler(IAsyncStreamReader<TResponse> streamReader, Action completionCallback)
    {
        _streamReader = streamReader;
        _completionCallback = completionCallback;
    }

    public TResponse Current => _streamReader.Current;

    public async Task<bool> MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        try
        {
            var hasNext = await _streamReader.MoveNext(cancellationToken);

            if (!hasNext)
            {
                _completionCallback();
            }

            return hasNext;
        }
        catch (RpcException ex)
        {
            LogError(ex);
            _completionCallback();
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```